# out of all columns in a table, how can I find the one datatype that is cheapest and I could convert all other columns datatypes into?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, type-conversion, unpivot

I sometimes have to unpivot tables, that means, converting all columns into rows.

Generally that becomes a table with 2 columns (just to simplify things) - the first is the column name and the second is the column value.
.
In the example below I found out manually by looking at the column types in the original table, that the best column to store the `value` is `nvarchar(256)`.

**Questions:**

How could I find this *"the best value to use as the values column type is nvarchar(256)"* out dynamically?

I know I could use [sql_variant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for the values [column type](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/186555/22336)? In this case can I ignore the `collate database_default`?

That would be an expensive [overkill](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/1767/22336) - and I want to avoid that:

> sql_variant can have a maximum length of 8016 bytes. This includes
>   both the base type information and the base type value. The maximum
>   length of the actual base type value is 8,000 bytes.

```
--=============================================================================
-- Unpivot the table - SUCCESSFUL  
--=============================================================================

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB.DBO.#UNPIVOT') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #UNPIVOT

CREATE TABLE #UNPIVOT(
    [ColumnNames] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [AllCol] [nvarchar](256) NULL
) 

INSERT INTO #UNPIVOT([ColumnNames],[AllCol] )
SELECT
     ColumnNames
    ,AllCol
    --INTO TABLEBACKUPS.DBO.UNPIVOT_
FROM (
        select
                [host_platform]                   = CAST (host_platform collate database_default as [nvarchar](256)),
                [host_distribution]               = CAST (host_distribution collate database_default as [nvarchar](256)),
                [host_release]                    = CAST (host_release collate database_default as [nvarchar](256)),
                [host_service_pack_level]         = CAST ([host_service_pack_level] collate database_default as [nvarchar](256)),
                [host_sku]                        = CAST ([host_sku]  as [nvarchar](256)),
                [os_language_version]             = CAST ([os_language_version]  as [nvarchar](256)),
                [host_architecture]               = CAST ([host_architecture] collate database_default as [nvarchar](256))
       from 
       sys.dm_os_host_info 
      ) Radhe
UNPIVOT
(
AllCol
FOR ColumnNames IN ( 
                      host_platform
                     ,host_distribution 
                     ,host_release  
                     ,host_service_pack_level   
                     ,host_sku
                     ,os_language_version   
                    ,host_architecture
                  )
) unpvt


SELECT [ColumnNames]
      ,[AllCol]
FROM #UNPIVOT
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this will suit you:

```
SELECT
    Unpivoted.*
INTO #Unpivoted
FROM sys.dm_os_host_info AS HI
CROSS APPLY 
(
    VALUES
        (N'host_platform', CONCAT(HI.host_platform, NULL)),
        (N'host_distribution', CONCAT(HI.host_distribution, NULL)),
        (N'host_release', CONCAT(HI.host_release, NULL)),
        (N'host_service_pack_level', CONCAT(HI.host_service_pack_level, NULL)),
        (N'host_sku', CONCAT(HI.host_sku, NULL)),
        (N'os_language_version', CONCAT(HI.os_language_version, NULL)),
        (N'host_architecture', CONCAT(HI.host_architecture, NULL))
) AS Unpivoted
    (ColumnName, TheValue);
```

SQL Server will automatically work out the minimal length and string type of the `CONCAT` results.

If you need to preserve the underlying type information, including collation, and can live with the more limited set of data types that can be held in `sql_variant`, use that:

```
SELECT
    Unpivoted.*
INTO #Unpivoted
FROM
(
    SELECT
        host_platform = CONVERT(sql_variant, HI.host_platform),
        host_distribution = CONVERT(sql_variant, HI.host_distribution),
        host_release = CONVERT(sql_variant, HI.host_release),
        host_service_pack_level = CONVERT(sql_variant, HI.host_service_pack_level),
        host_sku = CONVERT(sql_variant, HI.host_sku),
        os_language_version = CONVERT(sql_variant, HI.os_language_version),
        host_architecture = CONVERT(sql_variant, HI.host_architecture)
    FROM sys.dm_os_host_info AS HI
) AS HI
UNPIVOT
(
    TheValue FOR ColumnName IN 
    (
        host_platform, 
        host_distribution, 
        host_release, 
        host_service_pack_level, 
        host_sku, 
        os_language_version, 
        host_architecture
    )
) AS Unpivoted;
```